# Steepest Descent of a function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let f : $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function $f(x, y) = x^2 + (1/2)y^2$.

(a) Compute the gradient $\nabla f(x, y)$.

(b) If $(x(t), y(t))$ is a parameterized curve, what is the gradient at the point $(x(t), y(t))$?

(c) At $t = 0$ I’m at the point $(1, 1)$ and want to always walk so that the graph of $f$ decreases the fastest. I also want my instantaneous speed at time t to be the same as the length of the gradient vector where I’m at. If $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ is the parameterization of my path, how do I express mathematically (in terms of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$) these conditions?

I understand how to do part a $( \nabla f(x, y)=(2x,y)$. A little help pushing me in the right direction for parts b and c would be greatly appreciated as i am a little lost.

Comment: Do you have an explicit parameterization $t \rightarrow (x,y)$?

Comment: Your function is ambiguous.  Is it f(x,y)= x^2+ (1/2)y^2 or f(x,y)= x^2+ (2y^2)?  What did you get for part (a)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, I helped typesetting a bit, also we had to guess if you meant half of $y^2$ or 1 over $2y^2$. You can learn to typeset by reading about LaTeX online or MathJax here on the site. If we guessed wrong or you want to correct any error you made in your question you can always fix it by clicking "edit" button under the question. OK?